# Problems with using InputMask PrimeVue in Vue3

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, input-mask, primevue

Im trying to use InputMask from PrimeVue in project on Vue3
I have block in template tag:

```
<div class="sdf">
  <label for="basic">Basic</label>
  <InputMask mask="99-999999" v-model="val1" placeholder="99-999999" />
</div>
```

and i have script:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    val1: null,
  })
}
```

Everything seems okay, and console doesn't show any errors, but still, input is not visible, only label is shown. What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't register `InputMask`.

You could register it globally with [`app.component('InputMask', InputMask)`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#component):

```js
// main.js
const { createApp } = require('vue')
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InputMask from 'primevue/inputmask'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App)
  .use(PrimeVue)
  .component('InputMask', InputMask)
  .mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-primevue-inputmask?file=src/App.vue)